# Setting Headers flags option in libcurl library in C

Tags: c, libcurl

I am doing Post request and for that I have to set header content type as `application/json` for that I am writing the following code:

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");
res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,headers);
```

but when I compile the program the error is comming as

```
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Please help me out to set this Content type as `application/json` as soon as possible

Answer (score 5):

you must place your headers with...

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
```

...while...

```
CURLOPT_HEADER
```

...is meant to include the headers in the output

So your solution could be just replace `CURLOPT_HEADER` with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

Comment: I Tested with that also still its not working.Any other alternative.